# How to load an external php file during an “onclick” event?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I trying to load google map on tab click to shorten the page load. I don't receive any errors in console. Just empty div `<div class="gmap"></div>`, when this should look like this: `<div class="gmap"><iframe style="border: none;" width="350px" height="150px" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?myadress"></iframe></div>`. It seems that script isn't executed on click.

What am I doing wrong? I need to mention that I still learning.

### This is how the map script works: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/JakubSkowronski/dpq9nbfs/)

map.php

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../..' ));
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');

jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_module');
$moduleParams = new JRegistry();
$moduleParams->loadString($module->params);
?>
<div class="gmap" data-address="" data-lang="auto" data-width="350px" data-height="150px" data-zoom="12" data-bubble="false" data-pin-size="1" data-output="iframe"></div>
```

jquery.google-maps.js

```
// entire script above
// autoload maps
jQuery(function($) { $('.gmap').googleMaps(); });
```

### First try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".tab").click(function() {
        $.getScript(window.location.origin + "jquery.googlemap.js", function() {
            $(".div-inner").load("map.php");
        });
    });
});
```

### Second try

I also tried this way but without effect:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".tab").click(function() {
        $.getScript(window.location.origin + "/jquery.googlemap.js", function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                cache: false,
                url: '/map.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.div-inner').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Loading the html after the script, so the element it references doesn't exist at the time the script runs

Comment: You need to call `$('.gmap').googleMaps();` after you get the map from php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Thanks!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".tab").one('click', function() {
    $(".div-inner").append('<div class="gmap" data-address="New York"></div>');
    $.getScript(window.location.origin + '/jquery.googlemap.js', function() {
      $('.gmap').googleMaps();
    });
  });
```